# WIN32 API C-program : Combo Box has an empty list or not dropping down despite populating with CB_ADDSTRING

Tags: c++, c, winapi, combobox

I'm using Visual C++ 2008 to do a C-program using WIN32 API dialog using wide characters. Every controls are working so far but I have now added a Combo Box by drag-n-drop from Toolbox into the resource dialog. I've done the necessary coding (see below) but when I click the Combo Box, the list doesn't seems to be dropping down or is empty when I click on the Combo Box. However the last item ("ITEM 2") is displayed in the Combo Box. I'm putting the code in WM_INITDIALOG instead of WM_CREATE because my app only consists of one dialog box. Here is part of my code :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK BasicScanProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    HWND hWndComboBox;

    switch(uMsg)
    {

        case WM_INITDIALOG:

            hWndComboBox = GetDlgItem(hwnd,IDC_COMBO1); //gets handle
            SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, TEXT("ITEM 1")); //adds items
            SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, TEXT("ITEM 2"));
            SendMessage (hWndComboBox, CB_SETCURSEL, (WPARAM) 1, (LPARAM) 0); //display first item
```

I've tried the below with same results as above:

```
SendMessage (hWndComboBox, (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) "ITEM 1");
SendMessage (hWndComboBox, (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) "ITEM 2");
```

How do I display the two items (ITEM 1 and ITEM 2) in the dropdown list of my Combo Box when I click on the control?

Comment: Combobox controls use the height set in the dialog resource to define the height of the drop-down, and I suspect yours is only set high enough to show a single item. In the dialog editor, click the drop-down arrow of your combobox and it will expand to show the size of the dropped down list. Resize it to make it bigger.

Comment: I clicked the drop-down arrow of the combobox in the dialog editor but it doesn't expand. The whole combobox control gets selected instead.

Comment: Click it a second time. It will expand to look like this: https://imgur.com/a/oekowZ1

Comment: Yup, you're right Jonathan! Thxs. I upvoted!

Comment: For reference: [Why does the size of a combo box include the size of the drop-down?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060310-17/?p=31973) and [How do I get the dropped height of a combo box?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100920-00/?p=12813).

Comment: Thanks Iinspectable. That was really useful!

Comment: @Ezani Is this issue solved? If yes, you can share you solution as an answer.

Comment: @RitaHan, yes. Ok will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Yes this issue is solved. The problem does not lie anywhere in the coding but in MANUALLY RESIZING WITH YOUR MOUSE OR ARROW KEYS the HEIGHT of the Combo Box control IN THE RESOURCE EDITOR OF VISUAL C++ to ALSO account for the height of its dropdown list area when it drops (i.e. when it is clicked) PLUS the normal height of the Combo Box in normal non-dropdown mode. So the size (height) of the Combo Box control when you place it on the Resource Editor should be bigger than the default height of just the Combo Box control because its dropdown list area has not been expanded yet.

To change the height of the Combo Box control is a bit tricky. Your mouse cursor won't change to a resizing up/down arrow on your first click when you first click the Combo Box to select it. You will have to click the down arrow at the right end of the Combo Box again (yes, a second time). Then only will you be able to get the resizing up/down arrow. Many thanks to @JonathanPotter for this information!

Comment: Cheers Drake Wu!

Comment: you can also manually increase the height number in the .rc file where the control is. The last number represents the height so just increase that if doing it via the editor is too difficult.